# Unity 2D ignore collision by there tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well I have been working on a game in 2d , the game is similer to Age Of War i has a swords units and range units , all my units run the same script , i made a range unit detection so they can stop walking and start attacking this is it under the fixedUpdate Function:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (RangeUnit)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right, rayDistance);

        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject != gameObject)
        {
            Debug.Log(CC_Name);

            if (!hit.collider.CompareTag(gameObject.tag))
            {
                //if enemy
                ShouldMove = false;
                ShouldAttack = true;
                Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.green);
                CC_Name = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
            }
            else
            {
                //if friend
                Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(hit.collider, GetComponent<Collider2D>());
                Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.magenta);
            }
            Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            //if nothing
            ShouldAttack = false;
            ShouldMove = true;
            Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.red);
            Debug.Log("Hitted: Nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

in my example scene i have putted 3 units two in the left one is sword unit and another is range unit and in the right there is one sword unit, **MY PROBLEM** is when the range unit detect's the enemy unit in the right it stops and start attacking and comes the friendly sword unit from the left and kill's the enemy the range unit doesn't stop attacking and when i debug the CC_Name it tells that there is enemy on the raycast distance.

**ALL unit in the same layer but they have different tags**

I can't figure out how can i let this thing work properly

```
public void Death()
{
    if (Dead == true)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

~NOTE~: The Range unit Problem is if there is enemy and friendly unit attacking each other in the front of the range unit it does what it should do Stop's and start attacking but when the enemy dies it keep attacking untill the friendly unit go more then the raycast distance, it does what it should do if there is no enemy and there is friendly unit.

**is there a way to ignore collison totaly because when i debug the CC_Name it say's the friend name not the enemy name.**

Comment: Can you post the code that runs when the enemy gets killed? If the Raycast returns a non null collider, it means that that collider does not get destroyed/deactivated..

Comment: public void Death()
    {
        if (Dead == true)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

it Dead is true when health is <= 0

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your explanation on the bottom, Your ranged units have two issues:

- They flicker between attacking and not attacking when the enemy is alive
- They do not stop attacking when the enemy is dead.

The second one is simple, as the collider likely persists when the enemy dies. When the enemy dies, you should either destroy the enemy gameObject, or you can set these values on the enemy:

`//stops moving the rigid body independent of code RigidBody2D.bodyType = RigidBodyType2D.Kinematic;  collider.enabled = false; //disables all collision for dead unit RigidBody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero; //prevents velocity form carrying over`

This will prevent ray cast collisions with dead players as they do not have an active hitbox.

As for your first issue, look for other pieces of code that modify the attacking state.

Comment: the first scan that the range unit uses is good , but if it scan's after there is an enemy it think's that the friend after the enemys is an enemy

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reference to the targeted enemy to know when to attack or move rather than setting bools in the loop.

```
private GameObject _targetedEnemy;
private bool ShouldMove{get{return _targetedEnemy == null; }}
private bool ShouldAttack{get{return _targetedEnemy != null; }}
private bool EnemyIsInRange{get{return _targetedEnemy != null && Vector2.Distance(_targetedEnemy.position, transform.position) <= rayDistance; }}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (RangeUnit)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right, rayDistance);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            GameObject other = hit.collider.gameObject;

            //If raycast hit current target continue as is
            if(other != gameObject && other != _targetedEnemy)
            {
                Debug.Log(CC_Name);

                bool isFriendly = other.CompareTag(gameObject.tag);

                //Set new target enemy if not friendly
                if (!isFriendly)
                {
                    _targetedEnemy = other;

                    Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.green);
                    CC_Name = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
                }
                else
                {
                    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(hit.collider, GetComponent<Collider2D>());
                    Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.magenta);

                    //Set enemy to null incase it is just out of range and not destroyed
                    if(!EnemyIsInRange)
                    {
                        _targetedEnemy = null;
                    }
                }

                Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.yellow);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if nothing
            Debug.DrawRay(enemyDetecter.transform.position, transform.right * rayDistance, Color.red);
            Debug.Log("Hitted: Nothing");

            //Set to null incase it is just out of range and not destroyed
            if(!EnemyIsInRange)
            {
                _targetedEnemy = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should look at using Layermasks for oppposing sides though, it would simplify this, another option would be to use RaycastAll so it can get a reference to the enemy even if the a Friendly unit is between the Ranged unit and the Enemy Unit.